# tokyo cabinet & tyrant tutorial

Tags: tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

Can somebody refer a good tutorial on tokyo cabinet and tokyo tyrant

Answer (score 4):

Besides the official homepages for [Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) and [Tokyo Tyrant](http://1978th.net/tokyotyrant/), I've found [Ilya Grigorik's blog post](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/13/tokyo-cabinet-beyond-key-value-store/) quite informative, it also contains a link to his presentation on the subject.

Which language are you using with the Tokyo family btw?

**Edit**: James Edward Gray II's blog has these two interesting posts as well: [Tokyo Cabinet as a Key-Value Store](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/tokyo_cabinet_as_a_keyvalue_store) and [Tokyo Cabinet's Key-Value Database Types](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/tokyo_cabinets_keyvalue_database_types)

**Edit**: The first two links are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

A nice overview is given by Mikio Hirabayashi, the author of Tokyo Cabinet, [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/12016121/Tokyo-Cabinet-and-Tokyo-Tyrant-Presentation).

It is worth to have look at it to get an owerview over the variety of databases Tokyo Cabinet offers.